# htaccess rewrite rule from subfolder1 to subfolder2 not working properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I checked hundreds and hundreds of topics related to my issue and tried them all.
So far I can't get the result I am looking for:

I am trying to redirect a subfolder "stories" to another "news", except for the index.html and the subfolder itself.
And the whole thing in silent (url still showing the previous subfolder).

ps: the .htaccess file is located is the sub-directory and not the root of the domain.

meaning:

```
/stories/ --> /stories/
/stories/index.html --> /stories/index.html
/stories/whatever/ --> /news/whatever/ (but still showing /stories/whatever/)
/stories/whatever --> /news/whatever (but still showing /stories/whatever)
```

I tried this so far:

```
+FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/stories/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/stories/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /news/$1/ [P,L]
```

This is working for: /stories/whatever but if i add / at the end: 404 error. 
/stories/ and /stories/index.html are working if I copy the url in the address bar. but if I click through a link, it goes to /news/ and non silent (url showing /news/)

I am a bit lost and tried so many different ways:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Still can't get it work. Any suggestion ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It will work with you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/stories/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/stories/$
RewriteRule ^stories/(.*)$ /news/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Joker

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. Now /stories/ and /stories/index.html are working. if i paste the url in the address bar /stories/whatever/ is working also, but not through a link. How comes ? rules should be applied the same way no ?

Comment: I did not understand, give me an example to more understand the problem.

Comment: I changed the Rewrite rule to: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /news/$1 [R=301,NC,L] and now it is working correctly except if I don't put / at the end of the url.

Comment: you can use this

RewriteRule ^(.*)stories/(.*)$ /news/$2 [R=301,NC,L]

Comment: you can add the backslash using this code
RewriteRule ^(.*)stories/(.*)[^/]$ /news/$2 [R=301,NC,L]

Comment: don't forget to delete cache of browser, It causes many problems